# my javascript is not running

Tags: javascript, vb.net

In my page I have this area throwing errors:

```
<asp:Panel id="errorPanel" CssClass="errorclass" runat="server">
<fieldset>
<legend runat="server" id="errorlegent" class="errorlegentclass">Σφάλμα ελέγχου</legend>
<div id="errordiv" runat="server">
</div>
</fieldset>
</asp:Panel>
```

And in my code behind I have this script to send the error:

```
Dim element As String = "errordiv"
msg = "Some error message....."
Dim script As String = "<script type='text/javascript'> function() { document.getElementById(" + element + ").innerHTML = '" + msg + "'; } </script>"
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "myURL", script)
```

I see that the script have all the values I want. But the error message not seen in my page.

Comment: done any debugging yourself? You are generating JS, and could be introducing JS syntax errors, e.g. `msg` contains JS metacharacters, like a `'`' which terminates a string early and leaves the rest of what should be a string seen as JS code.

Comment: Yes I've done it and the messages is that `<script type='text/javascript'> function() { document.getElementById(ErrMessage).innerHTML = 'Error msg...'; } </script>

Comment: and where are you assigning this new function too? generally your code would either be `function foo() { ... }` or `foo = function() { ...}`. you'd defining a function but not assigning it a name, which means it has to be assigned to a variable instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was start when in Page_Load I had `Email.focus()`. 
I really can't understand how that blocks the script... but the truth is that it was block the script.
Thank you very much Marc B for his assistance... it was helpful from the aspect that something was wrong (typing error) in my code.